# Want to add # for perticular line vi editor

Tags: vi

Hello I want to add # at the beginning for few lines where content like /vol/home12 & vol/home14, line number not in sequence so I want to change with global option for file instead of going with sequence number

Answer (score 0):

A standard `vi` may not support alternation in regex, so two commands may be needed:

```
:g/\/vol\/home12/s/^/#/
:g/vol\/home14/s/^/#/
```

With `vim`, alternation (`\|`) can be used:

```
:g/\/vol\/home12\|vol\/home14/s/^#/
```

General form is: `:g/`**RE1**`/`**cmd**

This applies **cmd** to each line that matches **RE1**.

Here, **cmd** is: `s/`**RE2**`/`**str**`/`

**RE2** is `^`, which matches start of line.